VBA command button loading .tex file with writing
I have a Command button on a Userform 'Saving' which saves a sheet in Excel as CSV and then opens a .tex file.
For now, I manually enter the name of the CSV, but I was wondering if one could write the .tex file from VBA code. (i.e. making it easier for my colleagues to run the pdf creation)
Alternatively, I was wondering if you could have a message box appear which allows to copy that Range("D1") value.
(Ideally, if VBA code could also run the .tex file, but if it needs further programs to be installed, it will make life difficult to get my colleagues to download those).
Private Sub CmdB_Click()
'save the changes
        Dim CWB As String '.csv filename and location

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        CWB = Range("E1") & Range("D1")

        'create CSV file
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Copy

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=CWB, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
 
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        'open TeX file (to write or run?)
        CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\input.tex")

        Unload Saving
End Sub

.tex file
\documentclass[a4paper,12p]{article}

%Pricelist name to be entered
\newcommand{\pricelist}{241128_1135_CSV.csv} % Range("D1")

%%%% DON'T ALTER %%%%%
\input{input/RunPDF}


By inserting the following VBA code after Application.DisplayAlerts, I was able to write the .tex file as well as open it.
...
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        'open TeX file (write and run)
        Dim filePathT As String
     
            filePathT = Left(Range("D1"), 6) & ".tex" 'create filename

            Open filePathT For Output As #1 'create .tex file
                Print #1, "\documentclass[a4paper,12p]{article}" 'write into .tex file 
                Print #1, "\newcommand{\pricelist}{" & Cells(1, 4).Value & "}" 'and create all the lines needed
                Print #1, "\input{input/RunPDF}"
                Close #1 '.tex file is written
            
            'open Latex and call the created .tex file
                CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open (filePathT)
        
        Unload Saving 'close the Userform
End Sub


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
